# Maximum Subarray (BRUTE)

Tags: arrays, max, clrs

I was trying to implement the Brute method of Maximum Subarray problem, (clrs 4.1-2) and I thought I got it( quite easily ) as :
PSEUDO-CODE:

```
BRUTE-MAX-SUB-ARR(A)

1. from = -1 , to = -1, TSUM = -infinity
2. for i=0 to A.length-2
3.  sum = 0
4.  for j=i to A.length-2
5.   sum = sum+ A[i]
6.    if (sum > TSUM)
7.     TSUM = sum
8.     from = i
9.     to = j
10.    return(from,to,TSUM)
```

But the problem comes when it returns only one element `(from = to)`, therefore, we should consider a case when `from = to`, but this either excludes useful cases or includes redundant ones.

**EXAMPLE :**
If the input is 1,-4,3,-4 then it would return a wrong answer(like only the 3 that is the 3rd element).
Any Help Appreciated.
Moon

EDIT: 1) days changed to A.length
2) I wanted to know how do we handle the case when `from = to`, also having the maximum value of `sum`.
3) `0` changed to `sum` in the line number 5 of the Pseudo-code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 1. What is "days" in your algorithm. 2. If I'm not wrong, for [1,-4,3,-4] the maximum (contiguous) subarray *is* [3]. 3. The case `from=to` is covered in the inner for loop whenever it first runs (with `i=j`), you may need to fix it for `i=j=A.length-1` (meaning, the algorithm seems to ignore the last element like f.e. in [1,-5,4] will result in [1]).

Comment: Actually, this question includes an array describing the prices of a stock for 5 days that is, `{10,11,7,10,6}` and the array `{1,-4,3,-4}` , describes the change in the original array. The question asks to find the buying day and selling day of the stock such that the profit is maximum. So, we can't buy and sell the 3 $ profit stock on the same day. We can buy/sell   a stock only at the start of the day. Then the right answer would be `{1,-4,3}` which would give a profit of 0 $.